# Writable and ReadOnly data block for generic processing pipeline in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm am new to Rust and am trying to build a generic block-based processing pipeline. I want the blocks to be distinguished into `ReadableBlock` and `WritableBlock` but I want the underlying datatypes to be type-erased so that any data can be passed through the pipeline. The following example code demonstrates what I am going for (with all the pipeline specific code stripped away):

```rust
use std::any::Any;
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock, RwLockReadGuard, RwLockWriteGuard};

struct NullBlock {}

pub struct WritableBlock {
    inner: Arc<RwLock<Box<dyn Any>>>,
}

impl WritableBlock {
    pub fn new<T: 'static>(val: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: Arc::new(RwLock::new(Box::new(val))),
        }
    }

    pub fn write<T>(&self) -> Result<RwLockWriteGuard<'_, T>, String> {
        // How to return writable version of requested type?
        // If we can't downcast to requested type, return an error string
        Err(String::from("Failed to retrieve requested type"))
    }

    pub fn read<T>(&self) -> Result<RwLockReadGuard<'_, T>, String> {
        // How to return readable version of requested type?
        // If we can't downcast to requested type, return an error string
        Err(String::from("Failed to retrieve requested type"))
    }

    pub fn to_readable(&self) -> ReadableBlock {
        ReadableBlock {
            inner: self.inner.clone(),
        }
    }
}

pub struct ReadableBlock {
    inner: Arc<RwLock<Box<dyn Any>>>,
}

impl ReadableBlock {
    pub fn new<T: 'static>(val: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: Arc::new(RwLock::new(Box::new(val))),
        }
    }

    pub fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: self.inner.clone(),
        }
    }

    pub fn read<T>(&self) -> Result<RwLockReadGuard<'_, T>, String> {
        // How to return readable version of requested type?
        // If we can't downcast to requested type, return an error string
        Err(String::from("Failed to retrieve requested type"))
    }

    pub fn to_writable<T>(&self) -> Result<WritableBlock, String> {
        // Should clone the underlying the data into a new Writable block, i.e. perform Copy-On-Write
        // Does this require extra trait bounds on the stored data type? e.g. Something like Box<dyn Any + Clone>?
        // If we can't downcast to requested type, return an error string
        Err(String::from("Failed to retrieve requested type"))
    }
}

fn example_readonly(block: ReadableBlock) -> ReadableBlock {
    if let Ok(val) = block.read::<u64>() {
        println!("Read Only: {}", val);
    }

    println!("Failed example_readonly");
    block
}

fn example_modify(block: ReadableBlock) -> ReadableBlock {
    if let Ok(int_block) = block.to_writable::<u64>() {
        if let Ok(mut val) = int_block.write::<u64>() {
            *val += 1;
            return int_block.to_readable();
        }
    }

    println!("Failed example_modify");
    ReadableBlock::new(NullBlock {})
}

fn main() {
    let int_block = WritableBlock::new::<u64>(42);

    // Write/modify example
    let modified_block = example_modify(int_block.to_readable());

    // Read example
    example_readonly(modified_block);
}
```

This code should compile and run; however, it doesn't do what is expected. Namely, I am stuck trying to figure out how to implement `WritabeBlock::write<T>`, `WritabeBlock::read<T>`, `ReadableBlock::read<T>`, `ReadableBlock::to_writable<T>`. I could also be going about this in the wrong way. Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: The guard types for `RwLock` don't have a mechanism to "map" the internal type (i.e. you can ONLY get a `RwLockWriteGuard<'_, Box<dyn Any>>`). You will probably have to make your own `ReadGuard` and `WriteGuard` types that wrap those for `RwLock` to get the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`parking_lot`](https://docs.rs/parking_lot) supports mapping guards, so with it this is easy:

```rust
use parking_lot::{
    MappedRwLockReadGuard, MappedRwLockWriteGuard, RwLock, RwLockReadGuard, RwLockWriteGuard,
};
use std::any::Any;
use std::sync::Arc;

struct NullBlock {}

pub struct WritableBlock {
    inner: Arc<RwLock<Box<dyn Any>>>,
}

impl WritableBlock {
    pub fn new<T: 'static>(val: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: Arc::new(RwLock::new(Box::new(val))),
        }
    }

    pub fn write<T: 'static>(&self) -> Result<MappedRwLockWriteGuard<'_, T>, String> {
        RwLockWriteGuard::try_map(self.inner.write(), |v| v.downcast_mut())
            .map_err(|_| String::from("Failed to retrieve requested type"))
    }

    pub fn read<T: 'static>(&self) -> Result<MappedRwLockReadGuard<'_, T>, String> {
        RwLockReadGuard::try_map(self.inner.read(), |v| v.downcast_ref())
            .map_err(|_| String::from("Failed to retrieve requested type"))
    }

    pub fn to_readable(&self) -> ReadableBlock {
        ReadableBlock {
            inner: self.inner.clone(),
        }
    }
}

pub struct ReadableBlock {
    inner: Arc<RwLock<Box<dyn Any>>>,
}

impl ReadableBlock {
    pub fn new<T: 'static>(val: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: Arc::new(RwLock::new(Box::new(val))),
        }
    }

    pub fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: self.inner.clone(),
        }
    }

    pub fn read<T: 'static + std::fmt::Debug>(
        &self,
    ) -> Result<MappedRwLockReadGuard<'_, T>, String> {
        RwLockReadGuard::try_map(self.inner.read(), |v| v.downcast_ref())
            .map_err(|_| String::from("Failed to retrieve requested type"))
    }

    pub fn to_writable<T: 'static>(&self) -> Result<WritableBlock, String> {
        if !self.inner.read().is::<T>() {
            return Err(String::from("Failed to retrieve requested type"));
        }

        Ok(WritableBlock {
            inner: self.inner.clone(),
        })
    }
}

fn example_readonly(block: ReadableBlock) -> ReadableBlock {
    if let Ok(val) = block.read::<u64>() {
        println!("Read Only: {}", val);
    } else {
        println!("Failed example_readonly");
    }
    block
}

fn example_modify(block: ReadableBlock) -> ReadableBlock {
    if let Ok(int_block) = block.to_writable::<u64>() {
        if let Ok(mut val) = int_block.write::<u64>() {
            *val += 1;
            return int_block.to_readable();
        }
    }

    println!("Failed example_modify");
    ReadableBlock::new(NullBlock {})
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!